# In WebLogic JMX: What is the status of threads that are not Idle, Hogging nor Standby?

Tags: java, weblogic, jmx, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

[image]I am using WebLogic's Monitoring Dashboard (which allows us to monitor MBeans graphically, see attached image).

I'm monitoring: ExecuteThreadTotalCount, ExecuteThreadIdleCount, HoggingThreadCount and StandbyThreadCount.

I expected ExecuteThreadTotalCount to be equal to the sum of the other metrics, but it is always sightly higher.

Does anyone know what is the state of the missing threads?

Thanks[image: weblogic monitor screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

In WebLogic 11g the possible status of a thread is:

- Standby (i.e. in a pool where threads non currently needed are put by WebLogic)
- Idle (ready to take a new request)
- Active (a request is executing)
- Hogging (request is taking too much time to execute)
- Stuck (the configured StuckThreadMaxTime is exceeded)

So I think that in your count you are missing "Active" and "Stuck" threads. Unfortunately these counters seems not available in `weblogic.management.runtime.ThreadPoolRuntimeMBean` so you'll have to find the counter by yourself (maybe iterating on the thread list...).

See also [WebLogic 11g (10.3.6) admin console - servers,monitoring,threads](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/pagehelp/Corecoreserverservermonitorthreadstitle.html).

From my experience all the ready-to-use counters can be affected by problems and get wrong data, especially when the system is experiencing other issues (exceptions, errors, ...): as you may understand and error condition or a bug may cause a wrong update in a counter.